# Finding the Most Recurring Character

Tags: javascript, algorithm, for-loop, object, data-structures

```
function maxRecurringChar(text) {
  let charMap = {};
  let maxCharValue = 0;
  let maxChar = '';
  for (let char of text) {
    if (charMap.hasOwnProperty(char)) {
      charMap[char]++;
    } else {
      charMap[char] = 1;
    }
  }
  for (let char in charMap) {
    if (charMap[char] > maxCharValue) {
      maxCharValue = charMap[char];
      maxChar = char;
    }
  }
  return maxChar;
}
```

Here is the code I don't understand, cause first for always will return 1 , if always will return 1 why do we need to write the first loop?

[Here is the course link](https://scotch.io/courses/the-ultimate-guide-to-javascript-algorithms/finding-the-most-recurring-character)

Comment: The first for loop does not create a map with all char counts equal to 1. Because string equivalence is defined, different char objects will be the same key. When an equivalent char is encountered the second or third time, the count would be incremented. Regardless, without some snazzy built-in in whatever language, the loop is still necessary to allocate any kind of key-value pair for the chars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithm creates a new Object `charMap` to which all characters of the String text will be added as attributes. In the first for-loop you either add a new attribute with the name of the current char and set the counted value to 1 or, if already present, increment the counted value if the char was already found in the string. So you effectivly count for every char the number of occurences.

In the second for-loop the Object is searched for the greatest counted value, which will be the char with the highest count of occurences.